# InvalidOperationException ao utilizar o método Set do DatabaseContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, code-first

Ao utilizar o método DbContext.Set(), a seguinte exceção é levantada:

> The entity type  is not part of the model for the current
>   context

Caso eu crie um DbSet diretamente no DatabaseContext, funciona. Mas a minha necessidade atual é criar um repositório genérico, e a partir dele conseguir o DbSet referente a entidade passada em parâmetro, como mostra o código abaixo.

O que há de errado com a implementação para levantar esta exception? Estou utilizando CodeFirst.

**Controller**

```
public class QualquerController<TEntidade> : Controller
{
    public DatabaseContext contexto;

    public Repositorio<TEntidade> repositorio;

    public QualquerController()
    {
            repositorio = new Repositorio<TEntidade>(contexto);
    }
}
```

**Repositorio**

```
public class Repositorio<TEntidade> : where TEntidade : EntidadeBase
{
    public DbSet<TEntidade> Entidade;

    public Repositorio(DatabaseContext contexto)
    {
         Entidade = contexto.Set<TEntidade>();
    }
}
```

Comment: testa sem essa linha `Entidade = contexto.Set<TEntidade>();`. Acho que nao precisa disso

Comment: Oi Lucas, não estou em meu DbContext, então preciso desta linha para instanciar o DbSet. Se eu tiro, dá NullReferenceException.

Comment: Essa entidade que voce esta tentando adicionar ja existe nesse contexto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema através das dicas que Lucas me informou. Utilizando o método Entity do modelbuilder passado como parâmetro no método OnModelCreating, consegui registrar minhas entidades no contexto. Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
     public DatabaseContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>());
    }

     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>();

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A questão é que o método `contexto.Set<TEntidade>()` não adiciona essa entidade ao contexto. Ele apenas retorna um DbSet para você poder manipular o repositório.

Comment: Imaginei que fosse este o motivo, mas minha implementação segue vários exemplos na internet que supostamente funcionam... Você sabe algum modo de aprimorar este código para evitar esta exception? Como havia lhe dito, caso eu crie um DbSet<T> diretamente no DatabaseContext, este funciona corretamente, mas preciso faze-lo de modo genérico com n dbsets.

Comment: Como você vai gerenciar as tabelas no banco de dados se não coloca-lás no DBContext? Da forma que você quer fazer, uma tabela só vai existir quando o controller da entidade for chamado. Então digamos que voce tenha 2 tabelas. A primeira é chamada logo quando inicia a aplicação(neste momento ela é criada). E a segunda é chamada quando clica em algum link. Você vai criar as tabelas separadamente em tempo de execução caso elas não existam?

Comment: Lucas, como você sugere então? Preciso de um Repositorio genérico. Já trabalhei em projetos em que existia apenas um DbContext sem dbSet, contudo, o mapeamento das classes estavam no OnModelCreating. Eu não tenho este mapeamento porque estou utilizando data annotations. Existe uma outra forma de adicionar as tabelas ao contexto sem utilizar o dbSet para que eu possa manter a criação do dbset no repositorio, e não no context?

Comment: Vinícius, sempre há uma forma. Mas como eu disse no comentário acima, as tabelas precisam ser gerenciadas no classe do DBContext mesmo. Ou pelo DBSet ou pelo OnModelCreating.

Comment: Vou tentar explicar melhor a necessidade do gerenciamento centralizado. Você cria a tabela Clientes apenas quando acessa a página de clientes. Então você vai pra outra tela. Quando você voltar para a tela de clientes, você irá verificar de novo se a tabela existe? Isso irá consumir muitos recursos de máquina. E para se ter um gerenciamento centralizado, a única forma é com o DBContext. Todos as ORMs que eu conheço gerenciam as tabelas de forma centralizada. Tudo em um lugar só. E sempre verificado na inicialização da aplicação. Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Ajudou sim Lucas, através de seu comentário consegui realizar a inicialização das tabelas no OnModelCreating, como dito em minha resposta abaixo. Se tiver alguma pontuação sobre o método que implementei para registrar as tabelas no contexto, por favor, o faça :)